# How can I get correct infromation with params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I added column information to model User, that was generated by devise. I don't want to make user to fill field Information by registration. I created controller for other pages like profile

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def myprofile
    @currentUser = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
  end

  def userinfo
    @currentUser = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)

    if request.post?
      if @currentUser.update(params[:userinfo].permit(:information)) 
        redirect_to myprofile_path
      else
        render 'userinfo'
      end
    end
  end

end
```

On page userinfo user should be able to edit his information.

Here is view:

```
<div id="page_wrapper">

  <h2>Hey, <%= @currentUser.username %>, add some information about you: </h2>
  <%= form_for @currentUser.information do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :information %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :information, autofocus: true %>
    <p>

    <p>
      <%= f.submit "Save" %>
    <p>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :information, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :information, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :information, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

When I try to save it, I get

> undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass

How can I fix it? Maybe there is  better way to do this job? I don't want to show whole form to edit password, username etc. Only information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass

You are doing it wrong. Your `params` will not contain `:userinfo` key. Your `params` will look like this `:user => {:information => 'value'}`. You should change your code to below

```
#controller
def userinfo
  @currentUser = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)

  if @currentUser.update(user_params) 
    redirect_to myprofile_path
  else
    render 'userinfo'
  end
end

protected
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:information)
end
```

And also as you are trying to ***update*** a certain record, you need to change

```
<%= form_for @currentUser.information do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for @currentUser, method: put do |f| %>
```

Finally if you have set a `post` route for this corresponding `controller#action`, then you need to change it to `put`

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an other error. 

param is missing or the value is empty: user 


Why it happens?

Comment: @bg_mi Can you post the output of params that are generated?

Comment: here is my controller http://paste2.org/GCKmW7dw 
Does it metter, that I don't have methods create/update? 
Where can I read more about params and ways to use it?